# create new javascript object from variable

Tags: javascript, oop

i would like to create a new object in javascript (using simple inheritance) such that the class of the object is defined from a variable:

```
var class = 'Person';
var inst = new class
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can do something like

```
function Person(){};
var name = 'Person';
var inst = new this[name]
```

The key is just referencing the object that owns the function that's the constructor. This works fine in global scope but if you're dumping the code inside of a function, you might have to change the reference because `this` probably wont work.

**EDIT**: To pass parameters:

```
function Person(name){alert(name)};
var name = 'Person';
var inst = new this[name]('john')
```

Comment: You can also use `apply` to pass parameters, which is useful if you don't know them in advance, a.g. `this[name].apply(null, args)` where args is an array of parameters/arguments. Seems to be the case more often than not when calling functions dynamically.

Comment: This solution saved me having to use eval(). Thank you!

Comment: It seems that this solution force you to create a global variable. Do you know how to do this without leaking a global var ? I did not find a way to replace `this` by a suitable reference inside a function.

Comment: Any ideas how to accomplish this in coffeescript?

Creating a class based coffeescript app and would be good to be able to instantiate classes using a variable name.

Comment: @meder : nice answer. But how can we do it  in NodeJS. Where we don't have window object.  Any clue

Comment: `this` should be replaced with `window` in order to be able to use this inside of other bounds as [artfulrobot suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10819231/2065702)

Comment: this is not working in Chrome Extensions (background). window is not working either. Do you know why?

Answer (score 11):

Here's how I do it. Similar to meder's answer.

```
var className = 'Person'
// here's the trick: get a reference to the class object itself
// (I've assumed the class is defined in global scope)
var myclass = window[className];
// now you have a reference to the object, the new keyword will work:
var inst = new myclass('params','if','you','need','them');
```

Comment: Immensely helpful. Thank you. And this is better than Meder's answer, because you can pass `className` as a parameter in a parent function and thereby use it with any class due to the method of implication. At least, the way I've set it up.

Answer (score 1):

To put it more plainly, you can use `new` on a variable that references a class:

```js
class Person{}
const class_type = Person;
const instance = new class_type();
console.log("works?", instance instanceof Person); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

To improve on the answer above by meder:

To invoke using a function:

You would simply replace 'this' with the scope containing the class you are referring to, for example if the class is written in the global scope like below:

```
function Person(name){alert(name)};
var name = 'Person';

function classMaker(){
  var inst = new window[name]('john');
}

classMaker();
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem in Node.js, when I had to dynamically create different handler objects depending on the data. First I gathered all available handlers, which were implemented as separate modules, in an object. In a simple case this could be hardcoded like this.

```
var handlers = {
  handlerX : require('HandlerX'),
  handlerY : require('HandlerY')
};
```

Then, whenever I had to instantiate a handler, I did it like this:

```
var handlername = getHandlerName()
var handler = new handlers[handlername]();
```

Of course this only works if you know, or can programmatically determine the list of all objects you will need to create.

Answer (score -3):

This talk was really helpful when I got into different inheritance patterns in javascript. Example code is included in the second link (the video introduces it).

http://alexsexton.com/?p=94

http://alexsexton.com/inheritance/demo/

http://alexsexton.com/?p=51