# Create new class with variable name in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, class, google-chrome-extension

This is related to:
[create new javascript object from variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838898/create-new-javascript-object-from-variable)

But the solution from there (using window or this object) is not working in Chrome Extension background page.
When I go to console I can see my class if I type the name there, but is not inside "window" object.
Does somebody why is that and if there is a workaround?

Comment: You need to show [MCVE](/help/mcve) with manifest.json because currently it's unclear what exactly you're doing and which console you're opening, which `window` object you're inspecting. The background page is a separate hidden page with its own `window`, the web page has its own `window`, the content scripts run in isolated world so they have their own `window`.

Comment: Yes I know, I'm opening the background.html from the extensions page only, but for some reason global vars/classes declared in js files added to background.html are not part of window object

Comment: MCVE is still required. Without it we can only guess. Maybe you're using a compiler/bundler/modules, in which case you'll have to manually expose the variables using window.foo = foo;